# Spring Boot - logging.file property not having any effect?

Tags: spring-boot

I have written an application using Boot 1.0.0.RC1

The default logging configuration output works fine for my needs and according to http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html I should be able to set the logging.file property in application.properties to specify where the log file will be stored on disk.

This does not seem to have any effect though. My log ends up in /tmp/spring.log

logging.file property is defined in application.properties:

```
logging.file=/tmp/mylog.log
```

Output of mvn dependency:tree :

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |        \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.47:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:7.0.47:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:7.0.47:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:7.0.47:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.16.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.27:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.175:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.0.0.RC1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
```

So logback is on the classpath and picking up the default base.xml configuration from spring-boot.

Shouldn't the logging.file property work out of the box then, or do I need to configure it differently?

I know I can put logback.xml in classpath to configure logback directly that way and possibly include the default springboot logback configuration from base.xml but if I can achieve the same simply setting the logging.file property I would prefer that.

The approach I got working was to specify -DLOG_FILE=logs/output.log when running the embedded Tomcat using java -jar.

However I need to build a war and deploy that in a standalone Tomcat that I do not have access to reconfigure and set environment properties like the LOG_FILE property - so I need to be able to specify the log output using my application.properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated my pom.xml to use the 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version of Springboot and now it works just fine specifying the logging.file in application.properties.

Can anyone here tell me when (approximately) spring boot 1.0.0.RELEASE is scheduled for?

Cheers
Flemming

Comment: We always aim for a short RC phase. It really depends mainly on feedback (if a lot of issues show up it takes longer). RC2 should be next week and then hopefully another week or a bit more till GA, if nothing tricky shows up.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Good to hear that RC2 is near.